# Make a view swipeable and movable

Tags: android

I'm currently successfully moving my view with this code

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
        }
        root.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

If I press on the view and move my finger, the view follows it, now I would like to implement a swipe gesture, and it should work like this:
If I swipe starting from the background and hit the view, I would like it to play a rotation animation based on which direction the swipe was (up, down, left or right).
I still want to preserve the ability to move the views.

Imagine a coin, that I can move around, and if my finger flings it, it makes a 360° rotation

**EDIT:**
Here's how my code for rotating the view works, but it works only if I start from the inside of the view that has to be rotated

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    public final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override `OnTouch()` in your RelativeLayout and pass the MotionEvent on to a [SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html).  There you can return false for all the method except [onFling()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onFling%28android.view.MotionEvent,%20android.view.MotionEvent,%20float,%20float%29) where you check whether the first event was outside the view you're going to rotate and the second event was inside the view you're going to rotate.  If the events were not, you return false to indicate you didn't handle the event otherwise you rotate the coin and indicate that you handled the touch event by returning true.

As an extra point, I don't think you should be setting the right and bottom margins to -250 otherwise the view will extend to 250 pixels past the right and bottom edges of your RelativeLayout when I expect you want it to only extend to the intended width and height of the view respectively.

Comment: This way it wouldn't work as I have in mind, I would need to finish the fling inside the view for it to rotate.
I want to do something like fruit ninja, where you start the swipe and if you hit a fruit it gets cut.
I've updated my question with a piece of code, which works only if i start the fling from inside the view

in my case i would like to start the swipe, and if I hit the view it rotates (without the need to lift the finger from the screen or without the need to finish inside the view)

Comment: Touch events do not usually transfer from one View to another unless you return false from onTouch and then the touch event passes permanently to the next view up in the hierarchy.  For this reason, I would suggest you either: a) handle the entire process from the containing View's onTouch and go through its children to determine where the fling has happened, probably by providing a method that will determine whether coordinates are within the view space, or b) make the view that will rotate fill the parent view and use onDraw to ensure the contents is rendered in the right location.